# Is this possible to add binary file for a DART ONLY project?

Tags: dart

By using Flutter, I can use the `assets` in pubspec, but for DART ONLY project, is there any equalivant? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dart is just a language. You can load resources from the filesystem, the network or wherever however you please. Flutter uses the pubspec mechanism to know which assets need to be bundled into your app (APK, IPA, etc). If you are looking for strategies on how to best organize and load resources you should provide more details on what you are trying to achieve. Where are you getting your assets from? How do you want to use them once you have them loaded?